# When solving a big Rubik cube (100x100x100), do you reduce the solution to like 50x50x50, and then 25x25x25, and then like 10x10x10 and then 3x3x3?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, rubiks-cube

My question is about Rubiks cube.

Say you're solving a 100x100x100 cube (you can see examples in youtube by computer program - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cedyW6JdsQ)

When solving a big Rubik cube (100x100x100), do you reduce the solution to like 50x50x50, and then 25x25x25, and then like 10x10x10 and then 3x3x3?

What I mean is do you reduce big Rubik's cube to smaller Rubik's cubes by grouping patterns? It looks like computer groups patterns, and once it has grouped reds together, etc, it rotates the whole groups, and it gets quicker and quicker.

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks Norman, I add more tags!

Comment: I would imagine it would depend on who is solving it. There is a straightforward algorithm for solving any cube where you solve all the centers, then solve the edges which reduces your cube to a 3x3x3 cube.

Comment: Are you asking whether each person who answers would prefer such a strategy (which would be too subjective for SE, I think),or whether such a reduction strategy is _necessary_ for solving big cubes?

Comment: I don't know. Simply asking. :) Is this a valid strategy i guess.

Comment: Really, before you can objectively design a solution method you need to have a clear idea of what criteria make one solution better or worse than another.  Are you trying to reduce the number of moves?  The number of slice moves?  Solution time?  Intellectual difficulty?